# Filtering a Behaviour Subject used in a NgFor

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using a behaviourSubject in an Ngfor(cdkVirtualFor) as a way to watch for changes to a set of toggle buttons which filter the list of items by a TypeNumber.

Now my boss also wants to add a search input box to filter the same list based on a search term.

I am filtering the behaviour subject but as soon as I enter a search term in the input box the list goes blank and it does not return to normal if I clear the search box.

What am I doing wrong? I can filter a list when it is an array but when it is an Observable/BehaviourSubject I can't get it working.

Template

```
   <div class="field">
        <label class="label" for="searchinput-0">Search Input</label>
        <div class="control">
            <input id="searchinput-0" name="searchinput-0" type="text" placeholder="Search staff"
                class="input is-rounded  search-query" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm">
        </div>
    </div>
   <div class="notification column is-10">

    <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="100">

        <li *cdkVirtualFor="let p of courses" class="animated slideInRight">

            <div [ngSwitch]="p.typeNumber">
                <span *ngSwitchCase="1">
                    <lis-elearning [learningItem]="p"></lis-elearning>
                </span>
                <span *ngSwitchCase="2">
                    <lis-instructor [learningItem]="p"></lis-instructor>
                </span>
                <span *ngSwitchDefault>This the default case</span>
            </div>
        </li>

    </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

Component

```
constructor() {

  this.storage = { courses: [], filteredCourses: [], courseType: [], filterOptions: {}};
  this.coursesSubject = new BehaviorSubject([]) as BehaviorSubject<ILearningItem[]>;
  this.courseTypesSubject = new BehaviorSubject([]) as BehaviorSubject<ILearningType[]>;
  this.courses = this.coursesSubject.asObservable();
  this.courseType = this.courseTypesSubject.asObservable();
  }

// This setter is called everytime the value in the search text box changes

set searchTerm(value: string) {
 this._searchTerm = value;
 this.courses = this.filterCourses(value);
}

filterCourses(searchString: string) {
 return this.courses
 .pipe(map((courses) => courses.filter( course => course.Name === searchString)
 ));
}
```

**EDIT:** Added a Stackblitz - How do I add a searchbox that will filter the same list?  - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-multi-option-filter

Comment: Or if you can create a simple example on stackblitz and share it

Comment: How do I add a search input box to filter the list in this stackblitz? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-multi-option-filter

Comment: Could you please check my answer bellow

Answer (score 1):

Ok to solve the problem that created on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-multi-option-filter), just follow this steps :

1. First of install  `ngx-filter-pipe` using NPM (you can skip this, stackblitz is going to suggest you the install after )
2. Then `import { FilterPipeModule } from 'ngx-filter-pipe';` inside your `app.module` and add the `FilterPipeModule` to `imports[]`
3. In `app.component.ts` add a variable   `itemFilter:  any = { name: '' };`
4. In app-component.html change the `*ngFor` as follow `*ngFor="let item of courses | async |  filterBy: itemFilter"`
5. Inside `app.component.ts update`textFilter` function as bellow :

> ```
> public textFilter(ref){
>             this.itemFilter.name = ref;
> }
> ```

Everything should work as expected now

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new observables each time you type, getter functions that return observables are continually returning new observables. Use combine latest to create an observable.

```
searchTerm$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');

courses$ = IDontKnowWhereYouGetYourCoursesObservable;

filteredCourses$ = combineLatest(this.searchTerm$, this.courses$).pipe(
  map(([searchTerm, courses]) => courses.filter(course => course.Name === searchTerm))
)
```

and update the searchTerm$ with

```
<input (change)="searchTerm$.next($event.value)">

<li *cdkVirtualFor="let p of filteredCourses$ | async">
```

Comment: I tried the combinedLatest line but even if I put 2 new empty behaviourSubjects as the 2 values it won't let me do the .pipe as it says Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, [unknown, string, string]>

Comment: Are you running older RXJS versions? perhaps try the same thing with Observable.combineLatest()...

Comment: I am running Angular 8 and I believe all the latest versions of rxjs. If I prepend it with Observable. I get the following error: Property 'combineLatest' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'

Comment: Where are you importing `combineLatest` from? `combineLatest` is a creation function, not an operator, so it should be imported from `rxjs`, not `rxjs/operators`. (There *was* an operator by that name, but it is deprecated.)